# Python Requests lxml Encoding

Tags: python, encoding, python-requests

Help what to do. When you try to search, it often displays a name with an encoding error in the squeak. That is, for example (`Ð£ÐºÑÐ°Ð¸Ð½ÑÐºÐ¸Ð¹ VOD Ð¿Ð¾ÑÑÐ°Ð`)
Code

```
from base64 import encode
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring
from googlesearch import search
from time import sleep as wait
import os

os.system('cls || clear')
query = input('Уведіть ключові слова : ')
list_url = []


while 1:
    try:
        col = int(input('Количество запросов : '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Введите число')

for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=col, stop=col, pause=2):
    list_url.append(j)

if list_url != []:
    for i in list_url:
        wait(0.1)
        r = requests.get(i)
        tree = fromstring(r.content)
        Title = tree.findtext('.//title')
        print(f'\r[{Title}] - {i}\n')
    try:    
        os.remove('.google-cookie')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
else:
    print('Empty')
input('\nExit\n')
```

⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe page doesn't use `UTF-8` and you should use different encoding. OR maybe console/terminal use different encoding and it can't display it correctly.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `print( 'Украинский'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'latin1'))` returns `Ð£ÐºÑÐ°Ð¸Ð½ÑÐºÐ¸Ð¹`…